# Why I cannot enable the Apple Music library in my iTunes?

Tags: itunes, icloud, apple-music

[image]

As what this screenshot shows, every time I click the box to enable iCloud music library and then click "OK" to save the settings, the box will always remain unselected. As a result, I cannot use Apple Music.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  I don't have a good place that you can look for an error log other than the console, but before we start that, What happens if you make a new user account and try signing into iTunes Apple music there?

Comment: Sorry that I reply to you so late. I tried to sign out and sign in again,and fortunately it worked. I want to know where I can read the error log.

Comment: Excellent. Could you add that detail - signing in and out as an answer and list the time frame it took to resolve? Checking your answer as answered helps others here greatly. You can always uncheck the answer as well if the problem resurfaces and you have more data to add/share.